# Redirect returning users to a certain page?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, wp-redirect, authentication, template-redirect

Is there a way to redirect users returning to the site who are already logged in? Assuming something like:

```
function returning_redirect()
{
   //code here
}

add_action('auth_cookie_valid', 'returning_redirect');
```

But I can't seem to get any variation of that to work. Thanks!

Comment: Your initial idea _will_ work but you are going to trap users in a redirect. What criteria determines "returning" vs "not returning, just been here a long time"?

Comment: Basically, I'm looking to redirect anyone who has previously signed in and still remains signed in (using the "remember me" cookie) but, I want this redirect to happen only when they return to my site from some other site. Still possible? Is the 'auth_cookie_valid' the correct acton hook? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function redirect_user() {    
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
           wp_redirect( 'http://yoursite.com/page/' );
           exit;
        }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_user' );
```

This will redirect the user to the page of your choice if they are logged in.  It might be necessary to add a conditional that checks to make sure the user isn't already on that page, to avoid a continuous redirect loop.

Comment: This will trap a logged in user on that one single page.

Answer (score 0):

A bit crude but...

```
function returning_redirect($a) {
  remove_action('auth_cookie_valid', 'returning_redirect');
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    if (parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST) !== parse_url(site_url(), PHP_URL_HOST)) {
        wp_redirect(site_url('page'));
        exit;
    }
  }
  add_action('auth_cookie_valid', 'returning_redirect');
}
add_action('auth_cookie_valid', 'returning_redirect');
```

You are checking the `HTTP_REQUEST` header for a match against the server host name.

*Caveats*:

- That will not work on a server with multiple sub-directory installs
  like `http://site.com/wordpress` and `http://site.com/wordpress2`
  because that will only check the `site.com` part. If that is your
  circumstance you will need something more complicated.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is easily spoofed, but if there are no
  security issues that should be no problem.
- I expect that this is is going to be an annoying feature of your
  site.